# Changing variable in Java Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, variables

in JS, I have a list of variables, which I shuffle. I want to maintain the order of the shuffle, but change the values of the variables in the list. Is there a way to do that? Below is an example of my code. I explain what I want in the comments.

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var gen = "male "
var race = "white "
var rel = "christian "

var chars =[gen,race,rel]
chars = shuffle(chars); 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chars+"";

/*prints for example "white christian male " which is what I want

/*lets say I want to change the gender, and maintain the newly shuffled order (race-rel-gen in this case)*/ 

/* The below doesn't work. I want it to print "white christian female ", but it just reprints the original string*/

gen = "female "

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chars+"";
</script>
```

Comment: Your array isn't live, which means it won't update automatically.

Comment: so is there a way to make it "live"?

Comment: Shuffle is an arrangement of items in a random order. Do you mean sort?

Comment: @zer00ne no it randomly shuffles the order, does not sort.

Comment: *"...and maintain the pre-shuffled order"*, *"..."white christian male " which is what I want"* What is actually shuffled?

Comment: I mean maintain the shuffled order. Shuffle just randomly changes the order of the list. So originally it is gen-race-rel, after shuffle it became race-rel-gen. I want it to always STAY as race-rel-gen (or whatever order is produced by "shuffle")... with the ability to change the values of the variables.

Comment: @zer00ne OP is saying that he shuffles the variables in an array randomly, displays them, and then wants to alter the variables and display the changes in the same order they were initially shuffled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you want to maintain the pre-shuffled order, you can try to use an object, instead of string, then it'll keep reference. Something like this:

```
/* function to convert your array of objects into a pretty string */
const arrtoStr = (arr) => arr.map((obj) => obj.value).join(' ')

var gen = { value: "male" }
var race = { value: "white" }
var rel = { value: "christian" }

var chars =[gen,race,rel]
chars = shuffle(chars); 

//will output, for instance: "white christian male"
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrtoStr(chars);

// change object's key named 'value'
gen.value = "female"

//will output: "white christian female"    
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = arrtoStr(chars);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `map` object and some supplemental functions to take care of this.

```js
let char = new Map([
  ['gen', 'male'],
  ['race', 'white'],
  ['rel', 'christian'],
  ["order", shuffle([0,1,2])],
  ["display", ['gen', 'race', 'rel']]
]);

function shuffle(arr) {
  return arr.sort(_ => Math.random() > .5);
}

function display(mItm) {
return mItm.get("order").map(itm => mItm.get(mItm.get("display")[itm])); 
}

//display char
document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML += "</br>" + display(char);

//display new race
char.set("race", "blue");
document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML += "</br>" + display(char);

// reshuffle
char.set("order", shuffle(char.get("order")));
document.querySelector("#demo").innerHTML += "</br>" + display(char);
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the solution below should work. Keeping a `person` object and an `order` array separate should give you more flexibility. I am using [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) for `shuffle` as a convenience.

**[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/jackrugile/pen/e80c19aab96c283307c2cf3c16cc2e95?editors=0010)**

```
this.person = {
 gen: "male",
 race: "white",
 rel: "christian"
};

this.order = ["gen", "race", "rel"];

function output() {
  let temp = [];
  this.order.forEach((key) => {
    temp.push(this.person[key]);
  });
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp.join(", ") + "<br>";
}

// shuffle the order of properties
_.shuffle(this.order);

// output original data
output();

// change specifics, but keep the order of properties
this.person["gen"] = "female";
output();

this.person["race"] = "black";
output();

this.person["rel"] = "jewish";
output();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either assign the array again after assigning the new variable value like this:

```
var gen = "male "
var race = "white "
var rel = "christian "

var chars =[gen,race,rel]
chars = shuffle(chars); 

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chars+"";


gen = "female "
var chars =[gen,race,rel]
chars = shuffle(chars); 
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chars+"";
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/p6rgo01a/

---

Or create a reusable function like this:

```
function newVal(gen, race, rel) {
    var chars =[gen,race,rel]
    chars = shuffle(chars);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = chars+"";
}

newVal('male ','white ', 'christian ');

newVal('female','white ', 'christian ');
```

**jsFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/p6rgo01a/1/

Comment: this won't work. As everytime you call shuffle it changes the order. It should be called only once. It "randomly" shuffles.

Comment: Oh I see. So you want the initial shuffled order to stay but the variables assigned to change?

Comment: Yes! that is what I want

Comment: Let me try fiddling with the above snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You, possibly asked wrong question, or, your original intentions are not reflected in question, but as far as I understand, you are looking for sth like that.

```js
var races = ["caucasian", "ethiopian", "malayan", "american", "mongolian"];
var beliefs = ["jewish", "buddhist", "muslim", "christian", "shintoist"];
var genders = ["male", "female"];

var randomArrayElement = function(arr) {
  return arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
}

function makeCombo(r, b, g) {
  var race = randomArrayElement(r);
  var belief = randomArrayElement(b);
  var gender = randomArrayElement(g);
  return [race, belief, gender].join(" ");
}

document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function(e){
  document.getElementById("profile-area").innerText = makeCombo(races, beliefs, genders);
})
```

```html
<p id='profile-area'></p>
<button>Generate a profile</button>
```

Comment: I don't believe that answers my question. The randomization happens in the order of the list and happens only once. After that I want to be able to change the variables within the shuffled list, while maintain the order of the list.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a shuffle function. Something like this:

```
// define shuffle function
function shuffle(arr) {
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Then you can call this function with `chars` as a param to create a shuffled array like this:

```
var chars = [gen, race, rel];
```

You can then output the result as a string like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = shuffle(chars).join(" ");
```

The `join(" ")` to replace the comma with an space.

**option 1) reshuffle with new value(s)**

As your original `chars` array's order doesn't shuffle, you can change the value's by doing this:

`chars[0] = "female";`

You can update the DOM by calling the shuffle function again as shown above.

**option 2) keep the shuffled order en output it with an updated value**

To keep the shuffled order, but output the array again with an updated value, you need to store the shuffled output in a new variable. You will get something like this:

```
var chars = [gen, race, rel];
var shuffled = shuffle(chars);

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = shuffled;

// change value of gen
shuffled[shuffled.indexOf("male")] = "female";

// output again
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = shuffled;
```